# How to remove a specific role from everyone that has it Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Using Discord.js (V12)

I am currently trying to create a script that makes it so when someone says "what" the bot responds with "You are stuck with it!" then gives the user a role. But I want it so when the next person says what, it removes that role from the previous wielder. I currently have it working where it can add the role but not remove it from the previous person.

Here is my current working code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'what',
  description: 'Responds with You are stuck with it and adds role!',
  execute(message, args) {
    message.channel.send('You are stuck with it!');
    message.member.roles.add('886996311117795429')
  }
}
```

Comment: Just save `message.member` to a variable outside of your `module.exports`, such as `var previousMember`, at the end of your `execute()` method after you add the role to them. Then add `if (previousMember) previousMember.roles.remove("role id")` to the beginning of your `execute()`. It's very straightforward. If that's not good enough for ya, you can search through the guild member cache and filter out all members that have the role with the given role ID, and then use `.remove()` on each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of declaring variable inside your code like @Cannicide suggested is that if the bot goes down and you need to boot it up again, that variable will be lost.

The easiest way of having the data saved even after restarts is by using [**quick.db**](https://quickdb.js.org)

```js
//your other stuff if you have any
const db = require('quick.db')

module.exports = {
  name: 'what',
  description: 'Responds with You are stuck with it and adds role!',
  execute(message, args) {
    message.channel.send('You are stuck with it!');
    message.member.roles.add('886996311117795429')
    if(db.get('previousRoleUser')){
          let prevUser = message.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.id === db.get('previousRoleUser'));
          if(prevUser){
                prevUser.roles.remove('886996311117795429')
          }
    db.set('previousRoleUser', message.author.id)
  }
}
```

The above code is just an example, that is not tested. But I think it would work some how like that. Just set the value of the previous user to quick.db and then fetch the info from there when you want to use it.

Comment: You could also possibly use a message.guild.members.cache.filter function as well, would be more effective as sometimes attaching a database adds lots of confusion to some coders, generally well answered!!

Comment: Honestly, I would just use the guild member cache (or fetch the guild members) as Jeffplays2005 and I both mentioned in our comments. Eliminates the need for saving any data whatsoever, whether in a variable or database. Especially since even if the bot goes down, that approach would still work just as well as a database. Though either way works.